# Show that $C(T,v)$ is $T$-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $T:V \rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space $V$ over a filed $K$. Let $v \in V$ such that $v \neq 0$ and let $C(T,v)$ be the $T$-cyclic subspace of $V$ generated by $v$ (which means that $C(T,v)$ is the subspace spanned by $\{ v, T(v), T^2(v),...\} $). Is $C(T,v)$ a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$?

**My attempt:**

We claim that $C(T,v)$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.

Let $w \in C(T,v)$, then there exist scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3...$ such that:
$w = c_1 v + c_2 T(v) + c_3 T^2(v) +...$

Then $T(w)=T(c_1 v + c_2 T(v) + c_3 T^2(v) +...) = c_1T(v)+c_2T^2(v)+c_3T^3(v)+...$
since $T(w)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $v, T(v), T^2(v),...$ we have that $T(w) \in C(T,v)$ so $T(C(T,v)) \subset C(T,v)$ and therefore $C(T,v)$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.

The issue that I have with my proof is the fact that the linearity of $T$ is not always true with infinite sums.

Comment: You stated that $V$ is finite-dimensional. Therefore, the $T$-cyclic subspace has finite dimension and is spanned by a finite number of vectors, so you do not have to worry about infinite sums.

Comment: If $B\subset A$ then the linear span of $B$ is contained in the linear span of $A.$ Apply this to $A=\{T^nv\}_{n=0}^\infty$ and $B=T(A)\subset A.$

Answer (score 1):

$V$ is finite dimensional so the subspace $C(T,v)$ must also be finite dimensional. It follows that $C(T,v)$ is generated by a finite subset of $\{v, Tv,T^2v,T^3v,...\} $ That is any element of $C(T,v)$ can be written uniquely as a (finite) linear combination of
$$ \{T^{k_1}v,T^{k_2}v,...T^{k_{n}}v\}$$

Let $w \in C(T,v)$. Then $w = \sum_{i = 1}^l c_i T^{k_i}v \in C(T,v)$ for some $k_1,...,k_l$ and $c_1,...,c_l$. Then,

$$ T(w) = \sum_{i = 1}^l c_i T^{k_i + 1}v$$
which is a finite linear combination of $\{v, Tv,T^2v,T^3v,...\}$. By definition this means that $T(w) \in C(T,v)$ which proves that $C(T,v)$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$.